# Ahrefs reports that a page a few weeks old is ranking for few organic keywords

Tags: search-engine-indexing, keywords, ranking, ahrefs

We recently created a [web page](https://www.honestpaws.com/puppies-for-sale/). It's indexed on google and everything looks right when we check it through the search console but, for some reason, tools such as ahrefs and moz show there is are no keywords indexing for that page. This is the first time it happens to us and we are not sure why it's happening.

**Some other information that may be useful**

- We already have a couple of backlinks to the page from authoritative sites.
- It's a static site (gatsby / react)
- We use prerender.io for prerendering
- We use netlify for hosting
- The page was indexed about 2-3 weeks ago.
- According to Ahrefs, this is what they show under "organic keywords" section:

> In this report, we show the organic keywords for which any domain, URL, subdomain (e.g., blog.domain.com) or subfolder (e.g., domain.com/blog/) ranks. Use the drop-down to select your preferred mode.

- Here is an screenshot for what I see for the "problematic" page
  [image]
- Here is another screenshot for what I see for a page that was created/indexed some days after the "problematic" one was created [image]

Why are there no keywords being indexed?

Answer (score 1):

1. It might take time for google to place your page in the top 100 for any given keyword.
2. In some keywords you will never be placed in the top 100 with a new page without any backlinks.
3. Ahrefs knows the rankings of a certain page only if it looks up the keyword (probably because another user searched for it) and saves the SERPs to it's database. So it might be that the keywords for this page were not searched by Ahrefs lately, therefore your **new** page doesn't seem to be ranking.

The 3 points above combine into a possibility of why this happened.